# Couldn't open Assets/Plugins/x86_64/audioplugingvrunity.bundle

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I am new to Unity and Google VR SDK. I am running Unity 5.3.5 and on Mountain Lion OSX, with XCode 5.

I get the following error when trying to import the Google VR SDK into my project, and the demoScenes will therefore not run:

"Couldn't open Assets/Plugins/x86_64/audioplugingvrunity.bundle"

I see there has been similar errors reported in the past but I cannot see any solutions. Please could someone shed some light, if they have experienced this before and how I can resolve it ?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

As a temporary solution, can either rename the dll file into:
"audiopluginvrunity.dll" or modify the script "CardBoardAudio.cs", and fix the filename there in line:

```
  private const string pluginName = "audiopluginvrunity";
```